# Razorpay callback url doesnt calls

Tags: razorpay

```
 const payment = async (e) => {

 
      e.preventDefault();
    if(data.city==="" || data.email==="" || data.name===""||data.house ===""|| data.landmark==="" ||data.pincode===""||data.contact==="")
    {
      toast.error('Some fileds are empty!', {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored",
        })
    }else{
      try {
      
        const value = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/pay/getkey");
        setKey(value.data.key);
    
        console.log(key);
        const options = {
          key,
          amount: order.amount,
          currency: "INR",
          name: "Audiophile",
          description: "Test Transaction",
          image: "../../../public/images/home/desktop/headphone-hero-image.png",
          order_id: order.id,
          handler:async function (response){
            try{
          const responses=await axios.post("api/order/add",({ordertotal:order.amount,Shipping:data}))
          console.log(responses)
          setData({})
            }
            catch(err)
            {
              console.log(err)
            }
            
          },
          callback_url: "http://localhost:5000/api/pay/paymentverification",
       
          prefill: {
            name: "Gaurav Kumar",
            email: "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
            contact: "9000090000",
          },
          notes: {
            address: "Razorpay Corporate Office",
          },
          theme: {
            color: "#3399cc",
          },
          theme:{

          }
          
        };
        
        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
        rzp1.open();
      

        
      
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    
    };
```

I'm implementing a payment feature using Razorpay in my React app. Everything seems to be working fine except for the callback URL. I'm trying to set the callback_url property in the options object to the endpoint on my server where I want to verify the payment, but it doesn't seem to be working.when i remove the handler function the callback_rl works perfectly fine.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!